# Model send from PartialView to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I start work in asp.net-mvc and I have problem to send model from partialview to controller.
So first this is the way I create partialview

```
@Html.Partial("Weather", ShopB2B.Controllers.HomeController.GetWeather())
```

GetWeather() is controller metod that initializes first data to model. Model looks like this

```
public class Weather_m
    {

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> City_dropdown { get; set; }

        public string Temperature { get; set; }
    }
```

It is nesesery to DropDownListFor, and partialview looks like this

```
@model ShopB2B.Models.Weather_m

@using (@Html.BeginForm("GetWeatherNew", "Home", new { weather = Model }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.City_dropdown, Model.Miasta_dropdown)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Temperature, Model.Temperatura)</td>
            <td><<input type="submit" value="Send" class="submitLink" style=" height: 40px;" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    }
```

And here is problem because I want send this model to controller and then check which field is selected, add something, and send this model again to partialview. Any idea, how to do it?????

Answer (score 2):

You really should not be getting the data for your ViewModel type on view rendering.

Your data is type of `ShopB2B.Models.Weather_m`. Your strongly typed partial view expects this, this is all good. But instead of getting your `ShopB2B.Models.Weather_m` instentiated with `ShopB2B.Controllers.HomeController.GetWeather()`, you should create a ViewModel and return it to your strongly typed view, say `MyViewModel`. This should wrap an instance of `ShopB2B.Models.Weather_m`. So in your main view, your view would be strongly typed for:

```
@model ShopB2B.Models.MyViewModel
```

and you render your partial view like

```
@Html.Partial("Weather", Model.MyWeather_m)
```

I usually wrap the partial view inside the form as well, like:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("GetWeatherNew", "Home", new { weather = Model }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Partial("Weather", Model.MyWeather_m)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good pointers. There's only one thing that disturbs me in your answer: `new { weather = Model }` when building the HTML form. Don't forget that route values work  with simple properties, not complex objects.

Comment: Ok A. Burak Erbora, but problem is that i have other viewmodel in may main view, so I must adds this model to partialview in other way

Comment: @cyprian: why not add the weather model inside the viewmodel in your main view? After all, you want all this data in your final rendered page.

Comment: becouse this model will by change all the time, when somebody select DropDownList. If this hapend, form should send information about changes in dropdownlist to cotroller, he adds some new information and send it again. So this is reason why I dont now how to do it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use ajax for that bit instead of partial views. I suggest you take a look into that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should define the property bind to Dropdown appropriately. Since, you have defined the city_dropdown defined as IEnumarable so model binding will fails while sending from data to server due to data type mismatch (at client side City_dropdown will be generated as string for select control). In this case, you should change the property of Model as follows.

```
public class Weather_m
{

    public string City_dropdown { get; set; }

    public string Temperature { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.City_dropdown, Model.Miasta_dropdown)
```

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.City_dropdown, Model.Miasta_dropdown)

Comment: This is not possible to do there is two model?